# Cannot import apps in django project with vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

In vscode I am trying to import Apps in my django project.
But as below screen shot, I cannot import my apps in urls.py.
I also added my apps into mysettings(INSTALLED_APPS).

[image: vscode error]

Comment: can you check if you have django version > 2?

Comment: django version is 2.2

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue.
My solution is below.

1. run vscode
2. Ctrl + Shift + P
3. enter "Configure Language Specific"
4. select "Python", this will open settings.json
5. change false to true.
   "python.jediEnabled": true,
6. VScode will ask whethere install pylint. I installed pylint.
7. error just gone.

Comment: Can you please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server? If it works in Jedi it should work in the language server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem importing app, check whether your project root directory is added to pythonpath. If not, add it.

And, also notice that you need to add a comma(,) at the end of line no. 22

Comment: already added pythonpath in settings.json file. 

"python.pythonPath": "fcdjango_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"

Comment: try this: 
from fc_community.fcuser.views import home

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an error, it works properly on the real server.

This is version info of VSCode.

Version: 1.35.1 (user setup)
Commit: c7d83e57cd18f18026a8162d042843bda1bcf21f
Date: 2019-06-12T14:30:02.622Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134

Answer (score 0):

Your `fc_community` is the main folder for this Project. There are 2 things which you can do:

1. Reopen VS Code by `fc_community` as your root folder, right now `Django` is your root folder. This worked for me.
2. If you want to keep same root directory, you can add this to `.vscode/settings.json`

   ```
    {
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./fcdjango_view/fc_community"]
    }
   ```

It might work, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score -1):

you forgot to put `,` after `path('/',include('fcuser.urls'))`

it should be like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/',include('fcuser.urls')),
    path('/',home)
]
```

Comment: I added comma, but that is not main problem.

Comment: in vscode, there is a 'unresolved import' error, but when I run server in command, I can access server with no problem. I think there is a bug in VSCode environment with python and django.